# unable to get form_validation->set_rules and form_validation->set_message error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have autoload helper form and library form-validation in autoload.php

```
 <?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Login extends CI_Controller {


    var $data;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data=array('page'=>'login_view','title'=>'login');
           $this->load->model("Login_model");

    }
  public function index()
 {
      //get the posted values
    $data=$this->data;
    $this->load->view('template',$data);

 }
 public function checklogin(){
    //form validation
        $data=$this->data;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' ,'Password','required|callback_verifyUser');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $this->load->view('template',$data);
        }
        else{

        }
 }
 public function verifyUser(){
    $name=$this->input->post('username');
    $pass=$this->input->post('password');
      $option=$this->input->post('optionlist');

    if($this->Login_model->login($name,$pass,$option)){
        return true;

    }else{
                    //user doesn't exist
           //echo "Wrong username and password";
         $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect officer_id or password. Please try again');
        return false;

    }

 }
}

?>
```

The problem is it doen't show any error message USERNAME IS REQUIRED OR PASSWORD IS REQUIRED WHEN I LEAVE IT BLANK . IT SIMPLY REDIRECTS TO LOGIN_VIEW.PHP WITHOUT SHOWING ANY ERROR MESSAGE THAT USERNAME IS LEFT BLANK

THE doc SAID FORM-VALIDATION IS USED FOR THe PURPOSE to show errors.

for the view login_view.php u can see form here  http://pastebin.com/T2zMYGn1

Comment: Hmmm...everything looks OK to me. Any chance you can show us the template.php view file?

Comment: yeh sure template.php http://pastebin.com/850jTAc5

Comment: you can have a look at the complete code if u wish https://github.com/rachidasen/nic/tree/learnigniter

Comment: The github code is different to the code you've posted.

Comment: just sync done alittle bit change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `echo validation_errors()` in view file (template.php) where you want to see error messages

Comment: already used <?=validation_errors();?> in the view login_view

Comment: Try this in `template.php` file as i said, it will work because your error firing there

Comment: nice, You may accept my answer. However your code not well structured & I can suggest better way if you want.

Comment: it worked but messaged placed at differnet positon due to placing at template.php http://picpaste.com/doubt-MM4DoGlx.png

Comment: You can show error individually even below of corresponding field. See how http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually